# Excel Remove only last characters if they match

Tags: excel-formula

I've been trying a few different ways to try and search and replace on excell to remove the last couple of characters.

For instance in one column I have `product name S`

I want to remove the " S" only.

I have tried some if formulas a swell and not had much luck. I'm assuming there is a simple regex that can be used for the search and replace e.g. " S/" that would just replace if its the last characters and has nothing after it.

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/) and [this](http://regexlib.com/(X(1)A(7F6bv2yWRxPaN9m8-FUKNKl3LhHsGNgeyLupJ3mwYgpz6IV2AnlkDAVNFCC5RbO3WcJbHNSWsefLYTzWwIBx_Q7oKrvuwlH63ecHPwPtVb2zbCUoq1rE_0mgFC8OOTcVUivFr4rTQzMxhGZrs7aDcT5mH2kdrpVOXQ6mUj_QZcY_-lezCmefFt42ll88Nqm80))/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) are my best friends whenever I delve in to Regular Expressions

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SUBSTITUTE function and replace the letters you want to remove with a unique character/ word / space  not appearing anywhere else in the booklet, depending on which part of the string you're trying to remove and what format you're trying to keep

then find and replace ( CTRL +F)  that word with the black (space) character

see how to use SUBSTITUTE function here:

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-substitute-function

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in the end of the string, I don't think you need regex or anything too sophisticated.

If I understand correctly, you want to get the original string (`product name S`) up until but not including something that appears at the end (`S`). This means that in your example, you want the 12 leftmost digits: the digits of the original string (14) minus the digits of the pattern (2) - this would give you `product name`. If the original string does not end with the pattern, you want the original string.

Therefore, I suggest the following:

=IF(RIGHT("original string",LEN("pattern"))="pattern",
LEFT("original string",LEN("original string")-LEN("pattern")),
"original string")

Check these examples:
[image]